# How can i configure apache tomcat to be remotely accesed with mobile phone

Tags: apache, tomcat6, remoting

I managed to configure my tomcat for remote access, but i can only access it with a desktop and a laptop. I cant access it with mobile phones.

Comment: Tomcat doesn't care what accesses it. How are you trying to access it? Through wifi? Are you on the same network? If this is running on a local network you need to be part of that network.

Comment: Yes i am accessing it through wifi. I first established a connection between the network and the phone, then when i try to input the address on the mobile browser, it fails to load the web page.